# How to unit test an impure function with many dependencies?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, state

I have this function which plays the role of the main function in my small script. However, it has five separate functions that it takes as input. My question is how do I go about testing it? I do not think I can have fewer dependencies. Do I only do the statement testing and branch, decision, path testing without checking how the state is affected?

```
function handleRowClick(curElementState, getIndexOfTr, areElementsSameByIndex, changeElementSelectedState, changeSelectedElementToClicked, tr) {
    const indexOfTr = getIndexOfTr(tr);

    if (areElementsSameByIndex(tr, indexOfTr)) {
        changeElementSelectedState(tr);
    } else {
        changeSelectedElementToClicked(tr, indexOfTr);
    }
}
```

This is the function to be tested.

```
function solve(){
const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
const curElementState = {
    curElementInd: -1,
    isCurElementSelected: false
};

function getIndexOfChildInParent(parent, child) {
    return Array.prototype.findIndex.call(parent.children, a=>{
        return child === a;
    });
}

function changeElementSelectedState(curElementState, selectElement, deselectElement, tr) {
    if (curElementState.isCurElementSelected) {
        deselectElement(tr);
        curElementState.isCurElementSelected = false;
    } else {
        selectElement(tr);
        curElementState.isCurElementSelected = true;
    }
}

function deselectElementIfSelected(tbody, deselectElement, curElementState) {
    if (curElementState.isCurElementSelected) {
        deselectElement(tbody.children[curElementState.curElementInd]);
    }
}

function selectElement(backgroundColor, element) {
    element.style.background = backgroundColor;
}

function deselectElement(backgroundColor, element) {
    element.style.background = backgroundColor;
}

function changeSelectedElement(curElementState, deselectElementIfSelected, selectElement, element, newIndex) {
    deselectElementIfSelected(curElementState);
    curElementState.curElementInd = newIndex;
    selectElement(element);
    curElementState.isCurElementSelected = true;
}

function areElementsSame(tbody, curElementState, element, indexOfElement) {
    return indexOfElement === curElementState.curElementInd;
}

function handleRowClick(curElementState, getIndexOfTr, areElementsSameByIndex, changeElementSelectedState, changeSelectedElementToClicked, tr) {
    const indexOfTr = getIndexOfTr(tr);

    if (areElementsSameByIndex(tr, indexOfTr)) {
        changeElementSelectedState(tr);
    } else {
        changeSelectedElementToClicked(tr, indexOfTr);
    }
}

const selectElementBound = selectElement.bind(undefined, "#413f5e");
const deselectElementBound = deselectElement.bind(undefined, "");
const deselectElementIfSelectedBound = deselectElementIfSelected.bind(undefined,
    tbody, deselectElementBound, curElementState);
const changeElementSelectedStateBound = changeElementSelectedState.bind(undefined,
    curElementState, selectElementBound, deselectElementBound);
const changeSelectedElementBound = changeSelectedElement.bind(undefined,
    curElementState, deselectElementIfSelectedBound, selectElementBound);
const areElementsSameBound = areElementsSame.bind(undefined,
    tbody, curElementState);
const indexOfChildInParentBound = getIndexOfChildInParent.bind(undefined,
    tbody);
const handleRowClickBound = handleRowClick.bind(undefined,
    curElementState, indexOfChildInParentBound, areElementsSameBound, changeElementSelectedStateBound, changeSelectedElementBound);

function handleTbodyClick(handleRowClick, evt) {
    const target = evt.target;
    const targetNodeName = target.nodeName;

    if (targetNodeName === "TR") {
        handleRowClick(target);
    }
    if (targetNodeName === "TD") {
        handleRowClick(target.parentNode);
    }
}

const handleTbodyClickBound = handleTbodyClick.bind(undefined, handleRowClickBound);

tbody.addEventListener("click", handleTbodyClickBound);
```

}

If I only do white-box testing, how do I test the whole solve function (it is currently attached to an onload event, but it will be changed to a DOMContentLoaded event handler) to make sure it is actually correctly implemented? Do I test it as if it were a system test?

Comment: It's just too complicated. You want to separate your "solve" logic from your "manipulating the DOM with the results from the solve function" logic. Then you can just test your solve logic in isolation. You should be able to pass inputs (not dom elements) to solve and solve should return you some data that you then transform onto the DOM.

Comment: If a function's only result is side-effects then if you want too test the function you *must* check the side-effects; that seems obvious. But you can mock the side-effects, e.g., pass in mocks and ensure they're called when they're supposed to be. You set up the mocks to sufficiently test the various code paths.

Comment: I do not see a lot of logic to be extracted except for areElementsSameByIndex and, in the case that it is false, I can extract the checking for whether the element is currently selected. My main problem is whether I simply use mocks or I also test it at length in the browser.